# How do I exclude a folder in compress-archive

Tags: powershell

Can I somehow exclude a folder when I compress an archive like this?

```
$compress = Compress-Archive $DestinationPath $DestinationPath\ARCHIVE\archiv-$DateTime.zip -CompressionLevel Fastest
```

Now it always saves the whole folder structure of `$destinationpath` to the archive, but since the archive is in the same folder, it always gets zipped into a new archive, making the archive double in size every time I run the command.

Comment: set the destination to outside of the directory and once compression is complete the move it in. or select the contents of the destination excluding the archive and then compress that

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use -update option of Compress-Archive. Select your subdirs with Get-ChildItem and Where

like it:

```
$YourDirToCompress="c:\temp"
$ZipFileResult="C:\temp10\result.zip"
$DirToExclude=@("test", "test1", "test2")

Get-ChildItem $YourDirToCompress -Directory  | 
           where { $_.Name -notin $DirToExclude} | 
              Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $ZipFileResult -Update
```

Comment: So there isn't like a simple argument like `--exclude myfile` like in Linux?

Comment: there is, you can do: `gci -exclude *ps1 | compress-archive`

Comment: - Directory only gets directories inside temp folder, so files inside temp folder are not present inside the final zip, and also you cannot exclude subfolders of subfolders in this way

Answer (score 30):

Get all the files you want to compress, excluding the files and folders you don't want compressed and then pass that to the cmdlet

```
# target path
$path = "C:\temp"
# construct archive path
$DateTime = (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss")
$destination = Join-Path $path "ARCHIVE\archive-$DateTime.zip"
# exclusion rules. Can use wild cards (*)
$exclude = @("_*.config","ARCHIVE","*.zip")
# get files to compress using exclusion filer
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $exclude
# compress
Compress-Archive -Path $files -DestinationPath $destination -CompressionLevel Fastest
```

Comment: The exclusion rules take effect only on the root folder, the wildcard rules will not take effect on subfolders. In this example Subfolder\xxx.zip will be zipped into the destination file.

Comment: This completely breaks the directory structure, though

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is rather old, but wanted to post my solution here. This solution has worked for me and I hope it may help someone else having the same issue.

I took the ideas from the previous answers and developed them a bit.

So generally speaking what you need to do is to create two lists, one for the files in the root directory and another one for directories (excluding the directory you'd want to omit). Then you need to concatenate these two lists together and put them into -Path parameter of Compress-Archive cmdlet.

Voila! It will create a .zip archive with all files and directories we need, preserving the directory structure.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path /RootDir -File 

$directories = Get-ChildItem -Path /RootDir -Recurse -Directory -Exclude DirToExclude

Compress-Archive -Path $($files + $directories) -DestinationPath Archive.zip
```

Comment: This solution also breaks the directory structure after the 2nd level.