# Create zip file by cmd exclude 1 file. Compress-Archive

Tags: powershell, cmd

I tried to zip files from a given folder excluding one folder doing it with one command.

It is based on [How do I exclude a folder in compress-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081488/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-in-compress-archive)

I am trying

```
powershell Compress-Archive -Path "Get-ChildItem * -Exclude Sql -Name" -DestinationPath ..\..\Products\File4.zip
```

It throws

> Compress-Archive : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '*'.

When I use command `powershell Get-ChildItem * -Exclude Sql -Name` it work.

It is possible to this it in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this syntax:

```
Compress-Archive -Path (Get-ChildItem * -Exclude Sql -Name) -DestinationPath .....
```